# I want UITableViewCell to completely cover up the entire screen in ios Swift?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

The problem here is I want the `UITableViewCell` to fully take the view of the cell and once I swipe down the other cell has to appear. What I have here is the other cell also appears on the same UITable screen. As you can see the title of the other news also can be seen in the `UITableView`. I want the first data to cover up the entire screen and once I swipe down the next data(title,image,description) has to be added.

[image]

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Can you show us some code that you've tried?

Comment: If you need a high degree of customisability, I would also suggest to take a look at UICollectionView.

Comment: please refere this link https://github.com/NikolaySohryakov/CardScrollView

Answer (score 3):

In viewDidLoad(), make paging enabled:

```
myTableView.isPagingEnabled = true
```

then assign height to your cells,

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
        return self.myTableView.frame.size.height
    }
```